# Blank page during Firebase deployment with Cloud Function rewrites in place

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a React app hosting by Firebase. In `firebase.json` file, I set up the following rewrites rules to add dynamic OG tag to each blog post. `addDynamicOG` is a Firebase cloud function. What it does is basically read out the original `index.html` file, then replace the OG placeholder with some dynamic values. Once it's done, the modified `index.html` file will be sent back to the client side.

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/blog/**",
        "function": "addDynamicOG"
      },
    ]
  },
```

One thing I noticed is during the deployment, I have no way to access any blog post here `/blog/***`. It only shows a blank page. But once the deployment is done, everything will be fine again. Can someone explain what happens here? Is there any way I can create a non-disruptive and non-interruptive deployment? Thanks!

Comment: how you are accessing the index.html file inside the function?

Comment: I added postbuild script to copy local index.html to functions folder. When being deployed, cloud function can access the copied index.html on the server side